# How to use/load an SVG icon for google maps in Angular >= 12 & Webpack 5

Tags: angular, svg, webpack

I recently migrated an app from Angular 11 & Webpack 4.x to latest Angular 13.x and Webpack 5.x

I use the current Google Maps API to display markers with custom SVG icons

Before the upgrade it was possible to initialize the icon this way:

```
private static defaultIcon: google.maps.Icon;

this.defaultIcon = {
    size: new google.maps.Size(26, 40),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(26, 40),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(13, 40),
    labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(13, 13),
    url: require("../../resources/default.svg").default
};
```

Now with Webpack 5 the "require" method was removed in favor of URL usage ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67683185/angular-12-upgrade-issue-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-fil))

```
new URL("../../resources/default.svg", import.meta.url);
```

But this is no appropriate replacement in combination with a google.maps.icon element, as this needs the relative URL as a string pointing directly to the SVG-file

I tried serveral ways to get it working, but nothing did the job

Hope someone can give me a solution

Thanks

Comment: Which changes did you make to your Webpack config while migrating from 4 to 5?

Comment: My Webpack configs are only used for some minor tasks, the mail work is managed by the Angular CLI